# Not able to split string into 2 char

Tags: nodemcu, code-review, error

I am trying to split an incoming string into 2 integer values since I have to control 2 dc motors with it. The processor is node MCU and I get following error:-

Com Port Reading:-

```
WiFi connected
Received: "84+62"
"84+62"

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffd90 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01b0
3fffff40:  2b343822 00223236 3ffee70c 40204148  
3fffff50:  3ffe85ee 3ffee6d8 3ffee70c 402043c5  
3fffff60:  3ffe85dc 3ffee70c 3ffee6d8 402043c5  
3fffff70:  3ffe85f0 3ffee69c 00000000 00000001  
3fffff80:  00000000 40200038 3ffefca4 0000000f  
3fffff90:  00000007 00000000 00000001 402048f9  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee744 40204984  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe851c 401009a5  
<<<stack<<<

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v951aeffa
~ld
```

Code:-

```
if (msg.length() > 0) {
        Serial.print("Received: "); Serial.println(msg);
        char charBuf[50];
        msg.toCharArray(charBuf, 50);
        Serial.println(charBuf);

        char left[3] = {};
        char right[3] = {};
        int n = 0;

        while (charBuf != 0) {
          for (int i = 0; i < strlen(charBuf); i ++) {
            if (charBuf[i] != '+') {
              left[n] += charBuf[i];
              n++;
            }
            else {
              n = 0;
              break;
            }
            right[n] += charBuf[i];
            n++;
          }
        }
        Serial.println("Left Motor: "); Serial.print(left);
        Serial.println("Right Motor: "); Serial.print(right);

    }
```

My desired result is following:-

```
Left Motor: 84
Right Motor: 62
```

So what changes I need to make?

Comment: your code loops in `while (charBuf != 0) {` until watchdog resets the MCU

Comment: Use `strtok()` to split your string.

Comment: can you show an example using strtok()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example sketch that uses `strtok()`.

```
char charBuf[] = "\"84+62\"";

// Set array size to maximum number of integers you will receive.
uint16_t myArray[2];

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  int counter = 0;
  char* pch = strtok(charBuf, "\"+");

  while(pch != NULL){
    myArray[counter] = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, "\"+");
    counter += 1;
  }

  // Print out the contents of the integer array.
  for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
    Serial.println(myArray[i]);
  }
}

void loop(){}
```

`myArray[0]` contains 84 and `myArray[1]` contains 62.

Answer (score 0):

You get this memory leak because you overflow the variable `right`. This does not happen in the for loop itself even though this could be implemented more straight forward. But it's the while loop that doesn't come to an end (`charBuf` doesn't change and will not become 0) and in the second iteration `n` will be 1 initially (due to `n++` at the end of the for loop). That causes the overflow at `right[n] += charBuf[i];`.

So: remove the `while` loop (and use `strtok()`).

Answer (score 0):

> "84+62"

The additional doublequote characters are part of your string and charBuf

```
    Serial.println(charBuf);  // Text with " and  +

    char* cpl = nullptr;
    char* cpr = nullptr; 
    for (char* cp = charBuf; *cp != 0; cp++) {
        if (*cp != '"' && ! cpl )  cpl = cp;
        if (*cp == '"') *cp = 0;           
        if (*cp == '+' ) {
          *cp = 0; // split
          cpr = cp+1;  
        }
    }
    Serial.println("Left Motor: "); Serial.println(atoi(cpl));
    Serial.println("Right Motor: "); Serial.print(atoi(cpr));
```